# Android interstitial ads orientation

Tags: android, view, admob, orientation, interstitial

is it possible to force interstitial Ads orientation to be portrait only ?

this is my code:

```
final PublisherInterstitialAd interstitialAd = new PublisherInterstitialAd(context);
interstitialAd
.setAdUnitId(adUnitId);

PublisherAdRequest adRequest = new PublisherAdRequest.Builder().build();
interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, and you would not want to.

The ads should be displayed in whatever orientation the user has the device. Forcing it to do otherwise provides a poor experience for the user and excessive and convoluted coding for you.

Comment: I'm not sure of the reason for the OP's original questions, but in my app, even though the app is locked to Landscape mode only, I have noticed that on phones (strangely not on tablets which are predominately used in landscape mode), interstitial ads still sometimes display in portrait mode which looks weird and is extremely annoying, so there may be a case for forcing the ad to show in a particular orientation.  Not sure if this is what the OP was getting at. Maybe they were experiencing a similar problem?

Comment: Hmm, I've never heard of that happening before. It sounds like the implementation of the interstitial has made an assumption about the orientation instead of using the current orientation. In any case I doubt there is much you can do about it.

Comment: I am getting portrait interstitials when locked into landscape mode at app start. So its not just limited to phones. Its consistent on my test platforms (this is an Android v3.2.1 Acer A500 considered to have an extra large screen 1280x800 screen with a density of 1. I haven't tried my own full page ads yet and see if they get served up portrait. If so its a advertiser problem.